# How deep or how many levels is Meteor reactivity on the MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Does meteor reactivity work with deep levels or embedded docs. Wanted to know if there is a limit on how I should build my DB also are their any meteor reactivity performance things to consider.

I know this is fine

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader"
}
```

But what about this

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: {
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }

              }
 }
```

Or this

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   addresses: {
                {
                  street: "123 Fake Street",
                  city: "Faketon",
                  settings: 
                  {
                   false: true,
                   power: false
                  }
                  state: "MA",
                  zip: "12345"
                }
              }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one, only the top level. Meteor communicates dataset changes to the client over DDP through a mechanism what's called merge-box. This is governed by livedata which itself is now a part of the DDP package.

Meteor whatches for changes on the document's top level fields by diffing their initial and new values and then sending the diff value over to the client for it to apply to its current state and update all dependant objects and methods through the Tracker methods.

So, regarding your examples, `'address.city'` changing from `'MA'` to `'NY'` or `'address.settings.false'` from `true` to `false` would invalidate the whole document and cause computations to rerun.

Still, Blaze is a very intelligent dom technology. Even though its computations on the template that uses those changed documents require a rerun, often times, it can detect if the changes are actually dom related or not, and act accordingly. This is not a 100% percent guarantee, though.

For reference, you can read a good summary of *merge-box* over at [meteorhacks](https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-mergebox.html) and you should also see for yourself how the document diffing works on the source of [livedata server](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/livedata_server.js#L141) especially the `diffDocument` method and related methods.

Comment: If it's only the top level, why would changing address.city cause computations to rerun?

Comment: Because `address.city` is embedded in `address` and in fact is stored as `address: {city: 'value'}` so when `value` changes, it will have meant `address` has changed